# Lubuntu randomly freezing

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

Lubuntu (and any other Linux distro I try including Ubuntu and Zorin) freeze randomly on me. Sometimes it's when I'm launching a program. Ubuntu almost always froze when I used the installation commands. When the computer freezes the screen usually looks "staticky" (it's a solid colour with diagonal lines of a different colour). This computer worked fine with Windows XP and Windows 7 and never froze.

Lubuntu was installed with a bootable USB drive (as were Ubuntu amd Zorin when I tried those). Freezing is definitely random because I can't replicate it by repeating what I was doing when it froze. Lubuntu is running on an old emachines el1320 desktop (yeah it's like 8 years old, I'm trying to make an emulation machine with it).

So far switching the graphics drivers to the original proprietary ones has fixed this.